# Display bytea to image, jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, web, byte

Can you help me convert a saved image to the database (bytea, in postgresql), to image and display it on a web page (jsp)?

I convert the image this way, and save on database:

```
    Part part = req.getPart("profilePic");

    byte[] prfilePic = new byte[(int) part.getSize()];
    InputStream stream = part.getInputStream();
    stream.read(prfilePic);
    stream.close();
```

But how can I convert from bytea to image again and display it?

Comment: You 1) get the image as a `byte[]`, 2) save that `byte[]` to the database, 3) retrieve it again as a `byte[]`, and then 4) send that back to the browser. Which step is blocking you?

Comment: In step 4, I've tried several ways, but I can not convert. That's just where my problem lies

Comment: There is nothing to convert. The `byte[]` *is* the image. You send it to the browser with a `Content-Type` header of `image/jpeg` or whatever the image type is.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, for all suport, i try this 

    String url = "data:image/jpeg;base64," +  Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(user.getProfilePic()); and solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get de bytea from database, use:

```
String url = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(user.getProfilePic());
session.setAttribute("url", url);
```

And use on jsp, using session:

```
<img src="${sessionScope.url}">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(prfilePic);
BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
```